# How do you call a class's method when it is assigned to a variable and inside a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been working on a combat based game, and have assigned the stats of the characters to within classes. An example is below.

```
class elf():
    def __init__(self):
        self.attack = 1
        self.defense = 2
        self.speed = 3

def function():
    global player
    player = elf()

print(player)
print(player.attack)
```

How would you code this so I can access the variable from within a class which is in a function?

Comment: You haven't called `function()`, so your code should throw errors.

Comment: So how would I phrase it? print(function.player.attack) ?

Comment: Going by the current trend of your code, just call `function()`. The `global` variable is then created. _However_, this is bad practice... you should avoid creating and using globals as much as possible within functions, it's bad practice.

Comment: Sorry, I think I stated it poorly. I am trying to access the self.attack stat from inside the elf() class. How would I go about calling it using the player variable? (Feel free to change it anyway you like.)

Comment: You should call function() before player.attack

Answer (score 3):

What you have written *would* work if you called your function before trying to access `player`:

```
class elf():
    def __init__(self):
        self.attack = 1
        self.defense = 2
        self.speed = 3

def function():
    global player
    player = elf()

function()
print(player)
print(player.attack)
```

But (likely) a better approach is to avoid `global` and return the `elf` instance.

```
class elf():
    def __init__(self):
        self.attack = 1
        self.defense = 2
        self.speed = 3

def function():
    return elf()


player = function()
print(player)
print(player.attack)
```

I realize you've provided a minimal example, so it's hard to say *for sure* that returning the instance is a better approach, but it's very likely, and will help reduce future errors.

Comment: That should do it. I just need to grab the stats out of the class so I can use them in the computations.